# ConstraintSets in MotionLayout without copy-pasting attributes

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to use MotionLayout for animations without any code, just XML.

When I make a ConstraintSets it works fine, if I use *all constraint attributes* (like `layout_width`, `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` etc), but I don't change them. Can I use the attributes, which I really change in animation only?

Another question connected to this: can I make a transition from *any* state? Fоr example I want to manage three case with three buttons. I can do it in six transitions (each state to others), but may be it is possible to make only three ones?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes & mostly.

**Long answer...**

In a MotionScene CostraitnSets are "derived" from the layout.
You can also derive from another ConstraintSet.
You can override attributes at various levels of granularity.

**Simple**:

```xml
<ConstraintSet>
<Constraint androdi:id="@+id/a 
  motion:top_margin="23dp"
  ...
  />
</ConstraintSet>
```

Simple only defined Constraint tags override the layout

**Sectioned:**

```xml
<ConstraintSet>
<Constraint androdi:id="@+id/a">
  <Layout motion:top_margin="23dp" ...\>
  <PropertySet android:alpha="0.3" ...\>
  <Transform android:scaleX="1.3" ...\>
  <Motion motion:transitionEasing="linear ...\>
 
  </ConstraintSet>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Only sections are replace if you have a  section all layout tags are replaced

**ConstraintOverrid:**

```xml
<ConstraintSet>
<ConstraintOVerride androdi:id="@+id/a" 
      motion:top_margin="23dp" 
      android:alpha="0.3"...\>
 
  </ConstraintSet>
</ConstraintSet>
```

Individual attributes are changed but you **cannot** use "anchor attributes" such as
layout_constraintTop_ToTopOf

**Second Question**
Medium answer: you can transition **to** any State
Typically transition are given to and from

```xml
 <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="6000">
        <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/button1" />
```

You can leave out the motion:constraintSetStart.

```xml
 <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="6000">
        <OnClick motion:targetId="@+id/button1" />
```

Which will mean on click can go to this state from any state. Even in transition between states!
You can see code like this [here](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/blob/85991a3c517fca2f9d7c21ce642ad0a2214fad2e/projects/MotionLayoutVerification/app/src/main/res/xml/verification_scene_013.xml)